# Expand environmental variable from grep output in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to bash scripting, and I'm just trying to get this working. What I'm trying to get is a script that cd's to the default download directory, e.g. /home/davide/Downloads, and downloads a file from there in Ubuntu. I'm getting the default download directory like:

```
OUTPUT=$(grep DOWNLOAD $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs)
DIR=$(echo $OUTPUT | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr "\"" "\n")
```

which is working fine. DIR is a string like:

```
$HOME/Downloads
```

The problem arises when I try to cd to it. It does something like:

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
```

which throws an error, while instead it should:

```
cd /home/davide/Downloads
```

I've searched quite a lot and it appears to me that the expansion should be completed. I've got it to expand by using the *eval* command, but it appears like it should be the very last resort.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does `echo "$OUTPUT"` show?

Comment: Your $DIR starts with a newline, do a `echo "-$DIR-"`

Comment: It shows: `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"`

Comment: And Your directoy is `"/home/davide/Downloads"` (with a `/` as first character) not `"<newline>/home/davide/Downloads"` (with a literal newline as first character).

Comment: Lars I tried echo `"-$DIR-"` it outputs like `-*newline*$HOME/Downloads-`

Comment: You could use `echo $OUTPUT | cut -f 2 -d "=" | sed 's/"//g` (with sed instead of tr).

Comment: Lars I understand what you mean, yet the variable is not expanded.

Comment: @Pax_1601 I see. You can use `echo $OUT | envsubst` to get $HOME substituted.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @LarsFischer can you please post your answer below so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @ Pax_1601 I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments there are two problems:

1. there is a newline in the `$DIR`. I believe this is the cause of your original error. I would suggest to use a different way to determine `$DIR`:

   ```
   DIR=$(echo $OUTPUT | sed -r 's/.*="(.*)"/\1/g')
   ```
2. the literal `$HOME` in the variable `$DIR` can be substituted with `envsubst` like

   ```
   DIR=$(echo $DIR | envsubst )
   ```

Comment: Actually using your first point did remove the newline in front of the path, but the variable was not expanded nevertheless. The second point solved the problem

Comment: @Pax_1601 yes you are right, both are steps are required, I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Using `gnu` provided `envsubst` that substitutes environment variables in shell format strings:

```
dir=$(awk -F '["=]+' '/DOWNLOAD/{print $2}' file | envsubst)
echo "$dir"
# will output /home/user/Downloads
cd "$dir"
```

Comment: Curious; why not `awk -F ... | envsubst` instead?  That seems much more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd "$(grep DOWNLOAD $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr "\"" "\n")"
```

Or, if that doesn't work:

```
cd "$(grep DOWNLOAD $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr "\"" "\n" | tr -d "\n")"
```